# I don't understand why my assembly code doesn't work

Tags: assembly

the goal of this code is to scan the database and every time the word "no" appears it will replace it with "**", the program will stop at the char '$'

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
String db ' no, I am not no ? yes no reality $'
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    mov bx, 0 
    cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
    jz exit
    cmp [word ptr bx], 'no'
    jz switch

first:
    inc bx
    cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
    jz exit
    cmp [word ptr bx], 'no'
    jnz first
switch: 
    mov [word ptr bx], '**'
    jmp first
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: You should elaborate on 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Could you please also say: What the code actually does any what you are expecting that the code does?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FCin An example is given - however no question!

Comment: sorry, I have fixed it now, it's my first time here

Comment: Since you don't actually print out the string after modification, the only way you would be able to tell it's not being modified is if you're running the code in a debugger (and either single-stepping or setting a breakpoint). And, if you're capable of doing that, you should be quite au fait with examining the data after each instruction to make sure it works.

Comment: It's quite likely that the assembler is treating `'no'` in your comparisons as `'o','n'` rather than `'n','o'`.

Comment: I'm using asm88 as my debugger , and the zero flag is equal to zero instead of 1 evry time it passes on the word no, and I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

What kind of *"database"*? `db` stands for "define byte", not database.

Also as you use it in conjunction with string literal, you are actually defining several bytes, not just one.

`jz exit` ... after compare it's more usual to use alias `je` as *"jump equal"* shortening - it's the same `jz` instruction, but reads better with compare against non zero value, for anyone reviewing your code.

`mov bx,0` that's fragile way to get offset of the data, rather use the defined label: `mov bx, OFFSET String` or `lea bx,[String]`.

Also you can reuse the loop code completely, if you will load the bx with `String-1` offset (first `inc bx` will fix it to +0 address). So you can avoid the two duplicate `cmp` instructions at the beginning.

And finally... check the listing file or disassembly, what kind of value is comparing `cmp [word ptr bx], 'no'`. As you didn't mention your assembler, it's impossible to tell, how yours does compile that.

The NASM for example has exception for string literals, it will assemble it as two bytes 'n', 'o' in the human-expected "string order" (word value `0x6F6E`), even if it is marked as `word` size value (but you are not using NASM, because `[word ptr bx]` would be invalid syntax there).

In MASM/TASM I guess the assembler will treat that `word` value as true 16 bit value, i.e. `'n'*256+'o' = 0x6E*256 + 0x6F = 0x6E6F`, i.e. it would detect "on" substring in memory, because x86 is little-endian, so `word 0x6E6F` is broken down into single bytes as `6F 6E = 'o', 'n'`.

Rather use `cmp [word ptr bx],('n' + 'o'*256)` to be sure the order of letters is correct (by little-endian way).

EDIT: I tried it with TASM 4.1 (wrote both variants, and used `/l` command line switch to produce listing file):

```
 16 0000  81 3F 6E6F         cmp [word ptr bx],'no'
 17 0004  81 3F 6F6E         cmp [word ptr bx],'n'+256*'o'
```

As you can see from the instruction opcodes (`81 3F 6E6F` vs `81 3F 6F6E`), your `'no'` is searching for substring "on".

<strike>Funny thing is, that you have to fully understand little-endian and byte vs word subtleties, because if you will check that machine code as ASCII text, the first variant contains "no" string (will search for "on"), and the second contains "on" string (will search for "no").</strike>

Actually I confused myself, in that opcode the word value is displayed as word value, i.e. `81 3F 6E6F` is in bytes `81 3F 6F 6E` and when viewed as ASCII, it would contain the wrong "on", which is the substring, which it looks for.

---

Why *256 works...

- `byte` is 8 bits.
- `word` is 16 bits.
- x86 machines are little-endian, and memory is addressable by single bytes.

That means, that when you instruct CPU to write `word` value, like 1500, it will store the least significant byte first, and then the most significant byte after it. In case of 1500 = that's two bytes, 220 and 5. Because 5*256 + 220 = 1500. In hexadecimal formatting (which makes it so much preferred by seasoned asm programmers) it's even easier to see: 1500 = `05DCh`, and the bytes stored are `0DCh` first, and `05h` next.

Now so called beginners "strings" in TASM are ASCII encoded, single letter = single byte (The modern UTF-8 encoding does use variable length of bytes per letter, although the codes with value under 128 are compatible with ASCII, so any 7bit ASCII text is also valid UTF-8 text).

So text like `' no, I am not no ? yes no reality $'` is assembled into bytes:

```
20 6E 6F 2C 20 49 20 61 6D 20 6E 6F 74 20 6E 6F 20 3F
20 79 65 73 20 6E 6F 20 72 65 61 6C 69 74 79 20 24
```

Notice the "no" is formed by two bytes `6E 6F`.

If you will read that as word value, like `mov ax,[String+1]`, the CPU will use little-endian encoding of word values, and `ax` will be equal to `06F6Eh` (the first byte is low 8 bits, second byte is high 8 bits).

Now by writing `'n' + 'o'*256` you are manually deciding which letter will be checked as first byte (`'n'` .. which is shortened from full math `'n' * 256^0` (by ^ I mean power here, not xor)), and which will be checked as second byte (`'o'*256` where 256 is first power of 256).

Where powers of 256 comes... each byte is 8 bits, so it can store values from 0 to 255 (when interpreted as unsigned integer), i.e. exactly 256 = 2<sup>8</sup> distinct values. So when you run out of values on single byte, and you do +1 to second higher byte, you are doing that at 256 boundaries... and third and fourth byte (for 32b values) are of 256<sup>2</sup> value and 256<sup>3</sup> value.

I.e. 32 bit value 16,909,060 will be stored in memory as four bytes `04 03 02 01`. To verify: 4 * 256<sup>0</sup> + 3 * 256<sup>1</sup> + 2 * 256<sup>2</sup> + 1 * 256<sup>3</sup> = 16,909,060  .... yaaay..

So if you want to check two letters at the same time, as a word value, you have to look for word value `06F6Eh` (to test first byte against `6Eh = 'n'` and second byte `6Fh = 'o'`).

Comment: I'm using TASM, so should I have any problem?

Comment: and I changed the begining like you said me (with the offset String - 1)

Comment: so what machine is produced by that `cmp`? Switch on listing file in TASM (`/l` option).  (actually I tried myself, as I have dosbox + tasm 4.1 ... also if you have TASM, you have also turbo debugger, just check your box with TASM installation disks)

Comment: @MichaelNovak I added TASM output and explanation... got somewhat tricky (confusing even me ;) )

Comment: I tried it with  cmp [word ptr bx],'n' + 'o' * 256 and it worked but I don't understand what was the problem and why multilping 'o' by 256 solved the problem. Thank you very much for the help and if you can explain me I will be very happy.

Comment: @MichaelNovak let me know if this was clear enough ... if not, refresh your binary math, and how values are stored in bits and what little-endian means. One more note... the original `'no'` constant is calculated by TASM to be `'o' + 'n'*256` (makes sort of sense, if you don't look at it as human string, but as numeric value)

Comment: thank you, I think I understand it now